# How to get the value of select tag present under a div

Tags: jquery

I have got a HTMl as shown below

```
<div class="cascade" id="T1">
   <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="col9 pull-left">
         <select class="m-wrap" tabindex="1" style="width:100%;">
            <option class="placeholder" selected="" disabled="">Select T1</option>
            <option value="Ice Creams">Ice Creams</option>
            <option value="Popcorn">Popcorn</option>
         </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col1 pull-left"><a href="#" class="btn mini green" style="margin-left:10px;"><i class="icon-plus"></i></a><a href="#" class="btn mini black"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></div>
      <div class="row-fluid">
         <div class="col9 pull-left"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have tried this way , but i am getting null

```
var T1 = $('#T1').find(".m-wrap").val();

alert(T1);
```

could anybody please help me

Comment: you have it disabled so you won't get it's value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting `null` cause the current `selected` is set to the `<option>` that *is actually* `disabled`.

Use `:selected` meta

```
var T1 = $('#T1').find(".m-wrap option:selected").val();
```

---

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/77Lyq4xf/)

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove the disabled attribute (disabled="") and its work

```
<option class="placeholder" selected="">Select T1</option>
```

OR if you want to keep the disabled attribute you have to call the selected option like this

```
var T1 = $('#T1').find(".m-wrap option:selected").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
   <head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      function getSelectedValue(){
         var T1 = $('#T1').find(".m-wrap").val();
         alert(T1);
      }
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="cascade" id="T1">
         <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col9 pull-left">
               <select class="m-wrap" tabindex="1" style="width:100%;" onclick="getSelectedValue()">
                  <option class="placeholder" selected="" disabled="">Select T1</option>
                  <option value="Ice Creams">Ice Creams</option>
                  <option value="Popcorn">Popcorn</option>
               </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col1 pull-left"><a href="#" class="btn mini green" style="margin-left:10px;"><i class="icon-plus"></i></a><a href="#" class="btn mini black"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
               <div class="col9 pull-left"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
<html>
```

please try this. thanks.

Comment: You should explain what you've changed